# My Phone is not detected only by my laptop but other

Tags: android, mobile, hardware, android-hardware

I have this issue with my phone and laptop. My phone is not detected by my laptop but is detected in other laptop and pc. To point when i connect other device same model and same brand my laptop actually detect. What could be the reason

Comment: To better understand or reproduce your problem, please provide additional information such as: Smartphone Model, Android Version, and Laptop OS.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the Driver for your Android Phone.
Also please check out the link and follow the fixes if they works

https://www.carlcare.com/global/tips-detail/what-to-do-if-phone-is-not-recognized-by-pc/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please install the latest USB drivers on the laptop, and also use the original cable of the mobile phone.

if you use the same Wi-Fi on your mobile and laptop, you can use wireless debugging.

Comment: How can i use wireless debugging for flutter development like Expo in reactnative.